# If $f$ is continuous and $3\geq f(x)\geq 1$ for all $x\in[0,1]$, show the integral inequality.

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, definite-integrals, integral-inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

If $f$ is continuous  and  $3\geq f(x)\geq 1$ for all $ x\in [0,1]$, show that $$ 1 \leq \int_0^1f(x)dx\int_0^1\Bigg(\frac{1}{f(x)}\Bigg)dx \leq \frac{4}{3}. $$

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

By C-S
$$ \int\limits_0^1f(x)dx\int\limits_0^1\frac{1}{f(x)}dx \geq \left(\int\limits_0^11dx\right)^2=1.$$
For the proof of the right inequality use the Schweitzer's inequality.

See here:

http://www.ssmrmh.ro/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/INTEGRAL-FORMS-FOR-SCHWEITZERS-AND-POLYA-SZEGOS-INEQUALITIES.pdf